# Why do I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property" error with this variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

In [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WyMsF/) I have two variables that would be either undefined or null. The script works if the first variable is initialised, but not if the second is used. You can test this by commenting out each one and running the script.

This is the code:

```
var test = $('.not-here').height(); // works with this variable
var test2 = $('.also-not-here').offset().top; // doesn't work with this

$('#output').append('yeah');
```

Why do I have this problem and how do I get around it?

Comment: You can't de-reference something that is undefined.  That's all there is to it.  When a jQuery selector returns no elements, jQuery still returns an empty set (ie something that **IS** defined).  When you call _.offset()_ on an empty set, it is undefined.  So... You can't invoke a method on the return value of _offset()_ in this case.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null

Comment: The issue is that `$('.also-not-here')` actually *is* an (empty) list, whereas `$('.also-not-here').offset()` is truly `undefined`.

Comment: Or to put it another way, jQuery protects you from undefined and null, but once you're out of its protection, you have to deal with it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your selectors are invalid, as such they return an empty jQuery result list.

Calling `.height()` on an empty result list returns `null`.
Calling `.offset()` on an empty result list also returns `null`.

The reason you get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null` in the second line is because you are trying to call `.top()` on the result of `offset()` which is `null`.

Basically you are trying to execute `null.top()`.

I don't know what your code is for but as a pure example you could check the results first before using them, similar to this:

```
var $elem1 = $('.not-here');
var $elem2 = $('.also-not-here');

if($elem1.length && $elem2.length){
    var test = $elem1.height();
    var test2 = $elem2.offset().top;

    $('#output').append('yeah');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.also-not-here').offset()` returns `null` if the node doesn't exist. That is how it works by design.

As you want a fix so your code doesn't break, you can do something like this:

```
var $node = $('.also-not-here');
var test2 = $node.length>0 ? $node.offset().top : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = $('.not-here').height();
```

This return you `null`, since there's no element `$('.not-here')`.

Again,

```
var test2 = $('.also-not-here').offset();
```

This also return you `null`, since there's no element `$('.also-not-here')` and we cannot read property `top` of null.

I would suggest to do this:

```
$.fn.isThere = function(){ return this.length > 0; }

var $selector = $('.also-not-here');
if ($selector.isThere()) {
    var test2 = $selector.offset().top;
}
```

Comment: removed the -1, sorry it's really a bad practice, specially since you are giving an example to a person learning.

Comment: I do apologize for that. I usually cache all the elements, if used more than once. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

The first one `test` is getting set to null. The second case you are trying to reference a property of a null value which will throw an exception.